# Submit html form data to webflux HandlerFunction

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have an html form submitting request to an HandlerFunction. But I get the error, "There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported for bodyType=com.reactive.ui.component.SearchQuery

Here is the form.

```
<form
            action="#"
            th:action="@{/search}"
            th:object="${searchQuery}"
            method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>traveling from</td>
                    <td><input
                        type="text"
                        th:field="*{origin}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>going to</td>
                    <td><input
                        type="text"
                        th:field="*{destination}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>planning on</td>
                    <td><input
                        type="text"
                        th:field="*{flightDate}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input
                        type="submit"
                        value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And here is the HandlerFunction.

```
public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> postSearch = request ->
    {
        Mono<SearchQuery>         sq      = request.bodyToMono(SearchQuery.class);
        Flux<Flight>              flights = this.searchClient.post()
                .uri("/search/get/")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(sq,
                                                  SearchQuery.class))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Flight.class);
        Map<String, Flux<Flight>> model   = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("flights",
                  flights);

        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .render("result",
                        model);
    };
```

Here is the Route.

```
@Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> search()
    {
        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> searchRoutes = RouterFunctions.route(GET("/"),
                                                                            uiHandler.search)
                .andRoute(POST("/search"),
                          uiHandler.postSearch);
        return searchRoutes;

    }
```

What should be done in this case? I saw code like this `Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String> map = request.body(BodyExtractors.toFormData());`but doesn't know how to use it in my case.

I think I am somewhere near the solution. This is the code I wrote. But now I get "Only one connection receive subscriber allowed." Where am I going wrong?

```
public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> postSearch = request ->
    {

        return request.body(BodyExtractors.toFormData())
                .map(value ->
                {
                    sq.setOrigin(value.getFirst("origin"));
                    sq.setDestination(value.getFirst("destination"));
                    sq.setFlightDate(value.getFirst("flightDate"));
                    System.out.println(sq);
                    Flux<Flight>      flights = this.searchClient.post()
                            .uri("/search/get/")
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(sq))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToFlux(Flight.class);
                    Map<String, Flux<Flight>> model = new HashMap<>();
                    model.put("flights",
                              flights);
                    return model;
                })
                .flatMap(model -> ServerResponse.ok()
                        .render("result",
                                model));

    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I got it. All along I was using request.body(BodyExtractors.toFormData()), God knows why!!, but what was required was just request.formData(). Pasting the code  here for somebody out there to benefit.
A little explanation. request.formData() returns `Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String>>`. First I map it to create a SearchQuery instance from the value submitted through POST, then flatMap it where I call another microservice to get a `Flux<Flight>`, then put that into a java.util.Map and return the ServerResponse. You can actually do it in a single flatMap instead of mapping and then flatMapping.

```
public HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> postSearch = request ->
    {
        return request.formData()
                .map(value ->
                {
                    SearchQuery sq = new SearchQuery();
                    sq.setOrigin(value.getFirst("origin"));
                    sq.setDestination(value.getFirst("destination"));
                    sq.setFlightDate(value.getFirst("flightDate"));
                    return sq;
                })
                .flatMap(sq ->
                {
                    Flux<Flight>      flights = this.searchClient.post()
                            .uri("/search/get/")
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(sq))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToFlux(Flight.class);
                    Map<String, Flux<Flight>> model = new HashMap<>();
                    model.put("flights",
                              flights);
                    return ServerResponse.ok()
                            .render("result",
                                    model);
                });

    };
```